# Pass array in promise chain

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm trying to send notifications for all guests who are invited to an event.

The below code works up to the `console.log(guestPlayerIds);` which returns `undefined`. What is the best way to pass `guestPlayerIds`?

```
exports.sendNewEventFcm = functions.database.ref('/fcm/{pushID}').onWrite(event => {

  const eventID = event.params.pushID;
  const dsnap = event.data.val();

  // Exit when the data is deleted.
  if (!event.data.exists()) {
    return;
  }

  let guests = Object.keys(dsnap);

  const promises = guests.map((data) => admin.database().ref('playerIds').child(data).once('value'));

  return Promise.all(promises).then(data => {

    let guestPlayerIds = [];

    let returns = data.map(item => {
      let itemVal = Object.keys(item.val())[0];
      console.log(Object.keys(item.val())[0])
      guestPlayerIds.push(itemVal);

    });
  }).then(guestPlayerIds => {
    console.log(guestPlayerIds);
  })

});
```

Comment: You're doing nothing with those `returns`. Did you mean to `return` them? Of course, you could just move the `console.log` in the previous callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `map` is good, but you should return something inside the callback, and then also return the result of the overall `map`:

```
return data.map(item => {
  let itemVal = Object.keys(item.val())[0];
  console.log(Object.keys(item.val())[0])
  return itemVal;
});
```

You actually don't need the array variable `guestPlayerIds` at that point. Only in the subsequent `then` you can use it like you already had it.